# TypeORM: Old migrations keep appearing in new migration files generated using CLI

Tags: mysql, nestjs, typeorm

In my nestjs project i'm using typeORM and mysql. I've set **synchronize: false** in my TypeOrmModuleOptions. My issue is some migration queries keep re-appearing in newer migration files generated using CLI command **npm run typeorm:cli -- migration:generate -n**  .Currently i'm removing those statements manually from the generated migration file before  running the migration file. Any reason that could trigger this behavior ??

Comment: Could you solve it? I am facing the same issue